# How Do I find DB Password when sshing into AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was told I could ssh into my instance and locate my Postgres DB password. I ssh'ed into Elastic Beanstalk but I have no idea where to locate the password.

Anyone know?

Comment: Check your EB's environmental variables. You can do this in console. Its sometimes passed using the variables.

Comment: Where is the location of the variables though?

Comment: You need more details in your question. Its not possible to provide any precise answer at present.

Comment: What detail is necessary and I will get it? Tks

Comment: First check your application files. I guess it connects to the DB. So locate file where it is done and inspect it.

Comment: Its called application file?

Comment: You will have some application running on the EB instance, e.g. a Flask website. Its files will be in `/var/app/current`. If the application connects to the DB it should be somewhere in its files.

Comment: I can see Dockerrun.aws.json and  Dockerrun.aws.json.develop in that folder